# Unknown column 'reportes.id_usuario' in 'on clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
  SELECT t.* , user_datos.user AS user_reportando, trans_datos.nombre AS trans_reportado
    FROM reportes t 
    INNER JOIN user_trans ut ON( t.id_transporte=ut.id_transporte)          
    INNER JOIN user_datos ON (reportes.id_usuario = user_datos.user_id)
    INNER JOIN trans_datos ON (reportes.id_transporte = trans_datos.trans_id)
        WHERE ut.id_usuario='206' 
    ORDER BY fecha_reporte DESC
```

but its return

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'reportes.id_usuario' in 'on clause'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting "t" as the alias for the reportes table. Try joining on the alias

```
    SELECT 
    t.* , 
    user_datos.user AS user_reportando, 
    trans_datos.nombre AS trans_reportado
FROM reportes t 
    INNER JOIN user_trans ut ON( t.id_transporte=ut.id_transporte)          
    INNER JOIN user_datos ON (t.id_usuario = user_datos.user_id)
    INNER JOIN trans_datos ON (t.id_transporte = trans_datos.trans_id)
        WHERE ut.id_usuario='206' 
    ORDER BY fecha_reporte DESC
```